# How to store object property values in an array, in typescript

Tags: typescript

I want to store the properties names of an object in an array, and store the corresponding value for each property in another array, the code succeeded in javascript but when I tried using it in typescript it throw an error:
the code:

```
const newClinicalData = {
    id: '111',
    patient_id: '123',
    patient_national_id: '333',
    dm: 'yes',
    htn: 'no',
    hcv: 'yes',
    hbv: 'no',
    hiv: 'yes',
    hcv_vriology: 'no',
    hbv_virology: 'yes',
    hiv_virology: 'no',
    ckd: 'no',
    disability: 'no',
    cardiac: 'yes'
}

let newColumns = [];
let newEntries = [];
for (const column in newClinicalData) {
    newColumns.push(column);
    newEntries.push(newClinicalData[column]);
}
```

When I used the same code in typescript,I got the following error; when pushing data to newEnteries array:
"**Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Clinical_Data_Type'.
No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Clinical_Data_Type'.**"

Comment: Your error mentions `Clinical_Data_Type` but your code doesn't show it. Please make your [code be self-containing](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because `column` is only recognized as a `string` and not `keyof typeof newClinicalData`.

You'll need to tell Typescript that `column` is meant to be a key of your object by specifying

`newEntries.push(newClinicalData[column as keyof typeof newClinicalData]);`

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBGCmB3AwgGwJZncAhqgIjlDjALwwDeAsAFAz0zoAmAXDAOQCM37ANLQxgAHIunhgoAfWZsuAJgDMfAQxFQxEyWFHg801hwVHldBkwC2sgJ7wIJwQAsoYWWBD2GD4ADdrtj-QOAEa+HG4BMA7ooew2dvymgT6S3gBO6CCoIADmVq7uCY4hKeipmTl5HHERUd4lZVm5+RHAANYG7OGFZugQOEHoGFCVnQUq9LipTOg4wH52tAC+tLSo8LAIKJkAruaQZDAA2gC6ANyr63BIAKIS6bYHJ+c0AGYgqTAAFKCQsKCouzAMBALxgAHkggAreDAKAAOla8CsEE+mzQmGweEIxAAlDjKOMrlsAXsIHChNsIA5vjs9jjnoJNrcoPcyRSqaikOisLgCEQcId-oCYDgIDBEVYQTBhkJ4FK0RgeVj+cd6UsgA)

Comment: This answers the question but can be improved. The point is that `typeof newClinicalData` does not have an index signature (`{[key:string]: string}`) allowing random strings as its keys and `column` is just a string

Comment: I would make the assertion earlier so you're not casting a value in every iteration of the loop: `type Clinical_Data_Type_Keys = keyof Clinical_Data_Type;
const keys: Clinical_Data_Type_Keys[] = Object.keys(newClinicalData) as Clinical_Data_Type_Keys[];` Then you can easily iterate over the object's keys with some type safety `for (const column of keys)`